# docker containers file access

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have run into a problem where my backend (NestJs) image upload function uploads images to backend container folder sat (/resources/images/avatar/image1.jpg).

Now, i want to access this image from frontend (Reactjs) container to display user avatart. However, UNKNOW_URL_SCHEME error displays.

here is my docker-compose config

```
backend:
container_name: backend
build:
  context: ./backend
  target: development
volumes:
  - ./backend:/usr/src/app
  - /usr/src/app/node_modules
ports:
  #- ${BACKEND_PORT}:${BACKEND_PORT}
  - 5000:4000
command: npm run start:dev
env_file:
  - .env
networks:
  - webnet
depends_on:
  - mongodb
  - rabbitmq
```

and

```
frontend:
container_name: Frontend
build:
  context: ./frontend
  target: development
volumes:
  - ./frontend:/usr/src/app
  - ./usr/src/app/node_modules
ports:
  - 3000:3000
stdin_open: true
environment:
  - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
  - CI=true
command: npm run start
networks:
  - webnet
depends_on:
  - backend
  - ms-consent
  - mongodb
  - rabbitmq
```

My Images are in the root folder of backend code,

```
/resources/images/avatar/image1.jpg
```

Now, in frontend, I refer to file location as below;

```
const image_default_path = 'backend://resources/images';
```

where i assume, backend:// is container name and i can access with it, however, i can't.

I would like to seek your help you have solved similar issue,

Comment: `UNKNOW_URL_SCHEME` indicates the connection method provided in a uri (http://, https://, ftp://.....) is unknown to the client. Looking at your frontend config example (and knowing only about your techno that it is javascript executed in your browser...), I suspect you have mixed-up things a bit. Since your are mapping internal 4000 port of your backend to 5000 on your localhost, I'm pretty sure what you need is `const image_default_path = 'http://localhost:5000/resources/images';` or something very close to that. If your backend talks https, modify accordingly.

Comment: i have used backend:// to display image file in frontend container from backend container. however, i have used http://localhost:5000/resources/image/avatar/imagename.jpg. but now can see that file not found.